# React Native and Firebase

Tags: firebase, reactjs, react-native

I just started to play around with Firebase and React Native, and I noticed 2 major problems:

1. React Native seems to break debugging in Chrome

[image: pic]

2. I get a Network error when tyring to use the createUser call.

Otherwise the integration seems to be awesome!

Comment: I'd suggest placing these issues on the github/bitbucket/etc. repository.

Comment: Not sure what github repo is getting installed on npm install firebase ...

Comment: Use their support alias: https://www.firebase.com/docs/help/

Comment: Both of these should be fixed in the latest firebase client (2.2.6).  Please try upgrading and if you still have issues, contact support@firebase.com

Comment: Having this same issue, even with 0.4.4 and 2.2.6. Elie, did you ever figure out what's going on?

Comment: @Stirman just head back from the Firebase team ... still waiting to hear back from them. Hopefully should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, You can use Firebase 2.2.7.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/firebase-talk/aoPNvQQsVUE/Kh1E5rjrCAkJ

It said that this is fixed with the latest release we just put out (2.2.7). 
And this issue was closed. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1149

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.